# Static HTML Page as Sharepoint page

Tags: html, sharepoint

I want to use my existing static HTML page as the sharepoint page(AS IS without any changes in look and feel). Is there a possibility and if so how....as I see from sharepoint to create pages it only shows me 2 options "Basic Page" and "Web Part Page" which both has a .aspx page. Can someone point me to the correct implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Upload your html page in `pages library` and change your `web application`  settings to permissive. That will do the trick.
-- Edit --

1. Go to Central Admin > Web Application management > choose your web application
2. Click on general settings and go to section that says `Browser File Handling`. By default it is set to `Strict`, make it `Permission` and save the change.

I hope this will help you correctly update the settings.

Comment: Can you please let me know the details..I am using Sharepoint for the first time and could not find page library.I could find only these libraries mentioned here http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-libraries-HA010174493.aspx

Comment: Go to Site Actions -> View all Site Content -> Under Libraries, you should see Pages library

Comment: Is it ok to keep this setting for the web application in Central Administration ?